# Obtain the vertices from a list of edges

Tags: list, prolog, graph-theory

My list contains a number of facts as its elements.I want to search if a number is a member of the list or not.

Here I defined the edge facts in my program.Now I want to check if the node 1 is a member of the list.

```
?-my([edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)],1,L).
false.
```

Comment: Nice problem, what is your question? and what does this has to do with AI?

Answer (score 2):

A simple two-liner predicate:

```
has_node(UV,L) :-
    member(edge(U,V), L),
    (UV = U; UV = V).
```

Or by using two `member/2` predicates:

```
has_node(UV,L) :-
    member(edge(U,V), L),
    member(UV, [U,V]).
```

and we then can query it in multiple directions:

```
?- has_node(N, [edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)]).
N = 1 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 1 ;
N = 4.

?- has_node(2, [edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)]).
true ;
true ;
false.

?- has_node(2,L).
L = [edge(2, _G1245)|_G1248] ;
L = [edge(_G1244, 2)|_G1248] ;
L = [_G1247, edge(2, _G1245)|_G1251] ;
L = [_G1247, edge(_G1244, 2)|_G1251] ;
L = [_G1247, _G1250, edge(2, _G1245)|_G1254] ;
L = [_G1247, _G1250, edge(_G1244, 2)|_G1254] ;
L = [_G1247, _G1250, _G1253, edge(2, _G1245)|_G1257] .

?- has_node(A,L).
L = [edge(A, _G1257)|_G1260] ;
L = [edge(_G1256, A)|_G1260] ;
L = [_G1259, edge(A, _G1257)|_G1263] ;
L = [_G1259, edge(_G1256, A)|_G1263] ;
L = [_G1259, _G1262, edge(A, _G1257)|_G1266] ;
L = [_G1259, _G1262, edge(_G1256, A)|_G1266] .
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to know what type of facts are in the list.

Assuming that facts take the form of **edge(u,v)** then the following very naive predicate should do:

```
node_exists(Node, [edge(U,_V)|_]) :-
   U =:= Node,
   !.
node_exists(Node, [edge(_U,V)|_]) :-
   V =:= Node,
   !.
node_exists(Node, [_|R1]) :-
   node_exists(Node, R1).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- node_exists(3, [edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)]).
true.

?- node_exists(2, [edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)]).
true.

?- node_exists(6, [edge(1,2),edge(2,3),edge(1,4)]).
false.
```

Answer (score -1):

Recursion is the power of Prolog and you can't ignore it when learning Prolog.

btw here is a solution which finds how many times a node exists in list.

```
lits([H|_],E) :-
   element(H,E).    
lits([_H|T],E) :-
   lits(T,E).   

element(edge(A,_B),A).
```